# Linux/Unix Replacing a pattern in a string and saving to a new file with sed

Tags: linux, design-patterns, sed

I have a task, to replace specific pattern in a string.
So far I tried commands like  `sed -e 's/text_to_find/text_to_replace/g' file` 
but I don't why it changed all string, not just a part which I wanted to change.

what I want to do is in every string that contains word `china` to add this `Tomas_proxy.lt`

To make it very clear, what I am looking for, there is file I am using:

```
987173,businesswirechina.com
988254,chinacfa.com
988808,1012china.com
989146,chinawise.ru
989561,chinaretailnews.com
989817,mobileinchina.cn
990894,cmt-china.com.cn
990965,chinajoy.net
992753,octaviachina.com
993238,chinadftzalex.com
993447,china-kena.com
```

And this is I would like to see in a new file

```
987173,Tomas_proxy.lt/businesswirechina.com
988254,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinacfa.com
988808,Tomas_proxy.lt/1012china.com
989146,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinawise.ru
989561,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinaretailnews.com
989817,Tomas_proxy.lt/mobileinchina.cn
990894,Tomas_proxy.lt/cmt-china.com.cn
990965,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinajoy.net
992753,Tomas_proxy.lt/octaviachina.com
993238,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinadftzalex.com
993447,Tomas_proxy.lt/china-kena.com
```

P.s. This is just example file, In real file I am using, not every line has word `china` ,there is 100000 strings and lets say about 500 has `china`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this `sed` command

```
sed 's/,\(.*china\)/,Tomas_proxy.lt\/\1/' FileName
```

or

```
sed 's/,\(.*china\)/,Tomas_proxy.lt\/\1/' FileName > NewFile
```

or

```
sed  -i.bak 's/,\(.*china\)/,Tomas_proxy.lt\/\1/' FileName
```

Comment: Before I try this one, will it saves changes to a new files?

Comment: You have to redirect the output  to new file or you can use `-i` option with changes in current file .See my updated answer.

Comment: Could you update your answer to clarify the exact behavior of each command? Do these three do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/[Cc]hina/s/,/,Tomas_proxy.lt\//' File > New_File
```

In all the lines matching `china` / `China` (change if you don't want case check), replace the first `,` with `,Tomas_proxy.lt/`. Output redirected to `New_File`.

If you want the changes to be in the same file, use `-i` (inplace option):

```
sed -i '/[Cc]hina/s/,/,Tomas_proxy.lt\//' File
```

Comment: Could I ask you to explain it a little bit, if  I understand it correctly,  `[Cc]hina` is for China and china,  `s/,` is for delimiters - not sure about that, next, why at the end of this command there is double  `//`

Comment: If I would ask you, to explain ti, step by step, for a newbie. ? :)
Tell if I am wrong  `[Cc]hina` stands from China & china
 `s/,` to find delimiters to search . ?
I am not very sure with the very beginning of this command, mostly with the part  `/s/,/,` 

Thank you for helping me .

Comment: Ok. :-) . 1) [Ch]ina => either "China" / "china". 2) General format for substitution is sed 's/pattern_tobe_replaced/new_pattern/'. Another format is sed '/pattern_present/s/pattern_tobe_replaced/new_pattern/' where substitution happens only if the line has "pattern_present" in it. This is the format we are using here. If [Cc]hina present, do the substitution. Substitute "," with ",Tomas_proxy.lt/". Can figure that out from the general pattern. Escape the "/" in "Tomas_proxy.lt/" => "Tomas_proxy.lt\/".More on "sed": http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html. Hope it helped.. Phew..I'm tired :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Her is an `awk` version:

```
awk '/china/ {sub(/,/,"&Tomas_proxy.lt/")} 1' file
987173,Tomas_proxy.lt/businesswirechina.com
988254,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinacfa.com
988808,Tomas_proxy.lt/1012china.com
989146,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinawise.ru
989561,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinaretailnews.com
989817,Tomas_proxy.lt/mobileinchina.cn
990894,Tomas_proxy.lt/cmt-china.com.cn
990965,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinajoy.net
992753,Tomas_proxy.lt/octaviachina.com
993238,Tomas_proxy.lt/chinadftzalex.com
993447,Tomas_proxy.lt/china-kena.com
```

Search for `china`, if found, replace `,` with `,Tomas_proxy.lt/`, then print all lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/china/ s#,#,Tomas_proxy.lt/#' YourFile
```

based on your sample and assuming first `,` is the place to insert your text in the line